# Charts in wicket

Tags: charts, wicket, jqplot, chart.js

I am looking for an alternative for jfree chats which can be easily used with wicket framework and free.I am now using version 1.4.15 of wicket.

I found chatjs and jqPlot with some examples in the net but not sure which is best and easy.

Can anyone suggest a good option.

Answer (score 2):

There are Wicked Charts:
http://wicked-charts.appspot.com/start/?1
https://github.com/thombergs/wicked-charts

It is an wrapper for the HighCharts JS library.

> Please note that while Wicked Charts is licensed under Apache 2.0
>   License, Highcharts itself is only free for non-commercial use. See
>   here: [[http://shop.highsoft.com/highcharts.html]](http://shop.highsoft.com/highcharts.html%5d)

Comment: this. i use it and am very satisfied with it.

Answer (score 1):

if you only need simple charts, you could use http://pingunaut.com/wicket-chartjs/examples
which adds a wicket friendly wrapper around chatjs

Answer (score 1):

There is also Wicket library for ShieldUI http://www.shieldui.com/ at https://github.com/shieldui/wicket-shieldui

Free for non-commercial use.

Answer (score 1):

I had he same issue time ago, and I opted for using a Javascript library ([flot](http://www.flotcharts.org/)). The integration was a bit odd but simple, because I had to "render" the dinamic Javascript code  (i.e. the chart data).

Example:

```
public class MyPage extends Page {
  private String js;

  public MyPage() {
    final StringBuilder jsBuf = new StringBuilder();
    jsBuf.append("$(document).ready(function() {\n");
    jsBuf.append("var options = { series: { pie: {  show: true, label: {show: false}, stroke: {width: 0.000001} } }, legend: { show: false } };");
    // ...
    js = jsBuf.toString();
  }

  @Override
  public void renderHead(IHeaderResponse response) {
    super.renderHead(response);
    response.render(JavaScriptHeaderItem.forScript(js, null));
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Apache Wicket wiki webpage also provide some [tutorials](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/WICKET/JFreeChart+and+wicket+example) regarding charts. See the left pane to navigate to the other tutorials.

These tutorials refers to the [JFreeChart](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/) tool.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: @manetsus I do not think that is better to improve my answer because the question does not require a profound answer. The creator of this question appear only to look for an advice for a good java charting tool for Apache Wicket framework and is what I do in my answer.

Comment: See my answer for the requested example